# R: ggplot2 trouble reading a csv data file, object and mapping error

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I am new to using the ggplot2 package and am unfortunately having trouble with the basics. My data set is in a csv comma delimited file which has been working in R using plot functions but doesn't seem to be working in ggplot2. My csv file looks as follows:

```
Depth Min Max Average Mode
34    2   38  5.64    2
44    2   25  6.27    2
etc....
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
Statsnineteen <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/Holly/Documents/Software Manuals/R
Stuff/Stats_nineteen.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
p1 <- ggplot(Max, Depth, data = Statsnineteen)
p1 <- p1 + layer(geom="path") + coord_flip()
```

It then comes up with the following error message between the two p1 lines:

```
Error in inherits(mapping, "uneval") : object 'Max' not found
```

I know it can read the table as when I use:

```
Statsnineteen <- read.table(file.....)
head(Statsnineteen, n=52)
```

It brings up my data table.
Don't suppose anyone knows if there is a command I've missed out or if there is something wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance for any help, Holly

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = Statsnineteen, aes(x=Max, y=Dept))
```

Comment: note that `p1 <- qplot(Max, Depth, data = Statsnineteen)` should also work. I think that the `ggplot` approach is much clearer.

Comment: If this answer has solved your problem please mark it as accepted. Doing so lets others know the question has been answered.